# Restoring an element's color to its original value when there's an overriding style formed with a parent selector

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

The Bootstrap stylesheet has:

```
pre code {
    color: inherit;
}
```

If my page now has an explicit `pre code { color: red; }`, the Bootstrap stylesheet style still takes precedence. Why?  [Edit: can ignore this question as it was due to the wrong order of definition.]

How do I make `color` for `pre code` to take the color that is computed for `code`, without hardcoding the color value?

Bootstrap has set the color for `code` to #383e3c based on the selected theme. I don't know the reason why it has set a different color for `pre code`. I would like my `pre code` to have the same color as `code`.

Comment: Do you load your stylesheet before or after the Bootstrap stylesheet?

Comment: Style defined within the page.

Comment: Are you defining it in the page before or after you load the Bootstrap stylesheet?

Comment: You are both right. My mistake. That's the first question. Second: is it possible to make my `pre code` color to that of `code`, without hardcoding?

Comment: don't think there is - if `code` has been defined and then `pre code` is overriding it, the only way to override that is then to reset it to whatever the initial `code` is defined as (or make the initial declaration for code `!important` - but I would recommend against that)

Answer (score 1):

Please load your style after bootstrap and also use parent class or element to override bootstrap CSS.
you can use your parent class in place of body.

```
body pre code { color: red; }
```

Comment: yes if you want to override CSS which is load after your CSS then it should be necessary Otherwise load your style at end of all styles.

Answer (score 0):

Append `!important` to your properties to get higher priority.

```css
pre code {
    color: #383e3c !important;
}
```

Or you can give an `id` to `code` element and resetting the override that `pre` causes by re-writting the attributes:

```css
pre code#id {
  color: #e83e8c;
}
```

And use the style sheets like this:

```
<link href="/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```